# Can you recommend any good books/PDF's on best practices using Source Control

Tags: version-control

I am developing software, alone, in C# using Visual Studio Professional 2010. I have been advised to use Visual SVN for source control.

Can you recommend and good books/PDF's/resources for somebody who has no prior knowledge of how to use source control and wants to learn.

Thankyou

Comment: I would imagine that the most useful resource on "getting the most out of" source control would be one targeted to your source control system of choice, but you've conspicuously omitted that choice from your question.

Comment: Sorry, I have added this now, I got a warning about my question being subjective and so wasn't sure if I should include this or not.

Comment: The question is still borderline subjective, even the way it is. Very subject to the close reason which reads *"This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."* I don't think including your choice of version control will put you over the edge. But don't let that deter you from further tweaking.

Comment: I have updated the question, is this any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual SVN is very probably a wrapper, i.e. a graphical client to [subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/); you should more care about the basics so a graphical client is not that important; you could (and perhaps even should sometimes) use subversion on the command line (with the `svn` command).

*subversion* has several good books about it, and the [online documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is a good book. There are also several books (e.g. at OReilly) about subversion.

However, you could reconsider your choice of using `svn`, in particular the fact that it is a centralized version control system, and that history is not available locally (only on the server); this means that you cannot use any `svn` command on a developer's laptop without connection to the `svn` server.

My feeling is that if you are just starting using version control, a distributed version control like [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) (or perhaps [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)) is probably much better. I would suggest you to reconsider your decision of going to `svn`. (I won't recommend `svn` for a new project, even if you are the sole developer).

All the version control systems I mention are free software and have good documentation; and you'll find good books about them.

Beware that various version control systems have slightly different terminology (for example *"checkout"* has not the same meaning in `svn` than in `git`), and even slightly different concepts and goals. And some similar operations (like branching) are costly in `svn` but easy in `git`

Wikipedia has good pages on [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), [comparisons of VC software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software), [distributed version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control_system), [svn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29), [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29).

I repeat that you should reconsider going to SVN for a new project. It makes sense when working on an existing project, but I won't recommend it for a new one.

Don't forget to backup your repository if you manage it itself. And you could buy (if working on proprietary software) or get freely (if working on free software) some version control hosting (e.g. [myversioncontrol](http://myversioncontrol.com), [gitorious](http://gitorious.org) and many others)